# How to map the last item using modelmapper in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, modelmapper

I am using below converter for converting entity to DTO. My requirement is to get the last review comment/date from list of review comments/dates and set it on DTO. But I have to convert all the review comments and is bit of overkill.

MappingUtil.java

```
Converter<List<SomeEntity>, List<SomeDTO>> converter = (ctx -> {
    return ctx.getSource().stream().map(someEntity-> {
        return convertEntityToDTO(someEntity);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
});

mapper.using(converter).map(ParentEntity::getSomeEntities, ParentDTO::setSomeDTOs);
```

ParentDTO.java

```
private String lastReviewComments;
private String lastReviewDate;

public void setSomeDTOs(List<SomeDTO> someDTOs) {
    final Optional<SomeDTO> someDTO = someDTOs.stream().reduce((first, second) -> second);
    if (someDTO.isPresent()) {
        this.lastReviewComments = someDTO.get().getReviewComments();
        this.lastReviewDate = DDMMYYYY_DATE_FORMAT.format(someDTO.get().getReviewDate());
    }
}
```

How can I change below line

```
    mapper.using(converter).map(ParentEntity::getSomeEntities, ParentDTO::setSomeDTOs);
```

to get the last entity and set the last review comment and last review date directly on `ParentDTO`?

I tried below code, but it gives me some `NullPointerException`.

```
 mapper.map(src -> {
            final Optional<SomeEntity> someEntity = src.getSomeEntities().stream().reduce((first, second) -> second);

            return someEntity.isPresent() ? someEntity.get().getEmbeddedSubEntity().getReviewComments() : "";
        }, SomeDTO::setLastReviewComments);
        mapper.map(src -> {
            final Optional<SomeEntity> someEntity = src.getSomeEntities().stream().reduce((first, second) -> second);
            return someEntity.isPresent() ? DATE_FORMAT.format(someEntity.get().getEmbeddedSubEntity().getReviewDate()) : "";
        }, SomeDTO::setLastReviewDate);
```

Comment: What is the NPE about? 
Using `stream.reduce((a, b) -> b)` to get the last element of a `List` is overkill as it iterates over each element, but if you really want to do it with `Stream` and `Optional`, then better do it simpler: `return stream.reduce((a, b) -> b).map(a -> a.getEmbeddedSubEntity().getReviewComments()).orElse("")`.